# Hilighting The Current Navigation Tab Using URL in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

Hilighing the current navigation tab using php url ,with and with out .php Extension

```
 //php code
function curPageName() {
return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}
$Current=curPageName();;
?>
```

//HTML,CSS

```
<li id=<?php if ("index.php"==$Current) echo "selected";else echo "";?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, I use something like this to get current page as active menu in navigation bar:

- Put `$page = "page_name"` in your pages, for example for `home page`, let it be `$page = "home"`
- Now in a common file, where your navigation bar's HTML resides, it should look something like this:

> `<li <?php echo ($page == 'home') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>
>   title="Home Page"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;
>   ?>">Home</a></li>`
>  `<li <?php echo ($page == 'article') ?
>   "class='active'" : ""; ?> title="Recent articles"><a href="<?php echo
>   BASE_URL; ?>/articles">Articles</a></li>`
>  `...`
>  `...`

- Style `active` class using CSS to achieve desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```
<?php

    function curPageName() {
    return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
    }
    $Current=curPageName();

   $nav_tabs=array('home','about','products','contacts');

   foreach($nav_tabs as $nav)
   {
          if($nav == $current)
         {
             echo"<li class='active' > <a href='$nav' > $nav </a></li>";
         }
         else
        {
             echo"<li  > <a href='$nav' > $nav </a></li>";
        }
   }
?>
```

// in CSS define active to highlight the tab

```
.active{
background-color:black;
font-white;
}
```