# using OR statement in IF condition in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hilighting The Current Navigation Tab Using URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731052/hilighting-the-current-navigation-tab-using-url-in-php)

hilighiting the current tab without php extension not working

```
<?php if ("index.php" || "index"==$Current) 
  {echo "selected";}else {echo "";}?>
```

Comment: What? Your subject, text, and code make no sense together.

Comment: You also seem to be trying to ask the same question here, 27 minutes ago: [Hilighting The Current Navigation Tab Using URL in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731052/hilighting-the-current-navigation-tab-using-url-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
<?php if ("index.php"==$Current || "index"==$Current) {
          echo "selected";
      }else {
          echo "";
      }
?>
```

What you wrote didn't really make sense.

Comment: It was legal syntax alright, it just didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
if ("index.php" || "index"==$Current)
```

already return true because

```
if ("index.php")
```

same

```
if ("index.php" != "")
```